# Windows command prompt: escape special characters within quotation marks

Tags: windows, command-line, special-characters, quotations

I´d like to untar a tar.gz file with 7-Zip using this command:

```
forfiles /M *tar.gz /C "cmd /c "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" e @path"
```

but I can´t make it work because of the whitespace within `Program Files`. How can I escape it?

**Update:**

My alternative solution is:

```
set 7ZPath="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z"
%7ZPath% e *.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**forfiles /M *tar.gz /C "cmd /c "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z" e @path"**

Comment: This would make the code more robust if it worked - Use of the environment variable instead of hard coding makes the code more portable. But it does not solve the problem of the dissapearing quotes causing white space problem.

Answer (score 1):

Quotes within your FORFILES command string must be escaped as `\"`

```
forfiles /M *tar.gz /C "cmd /c \"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z\" e @path"
```